# glfwOpenWindow and glReadPixels modes?

Tags: opengl, mode, glreadpixels

Suppose I open a glfw window with:

```
glfwOpenWindow(width, height, 8,8,8,8,8,8, GLFW_WINDOW);
```

Then, I try to read it back with:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, ..1.., ..2..);
```

I'm not sure what I should be putting in as ..1.. and ..2.. ; I think ..1.. should be GL_RGBA, but no idea for ..2..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it helps, but I've found this article on [GPWiki about glfwOpenWindow](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/C:GLFW_Basics) and the [openGL docs for glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

I've played with openGL a bit, but I haven't used these functions. 
Could you try something basic like:

```
glfwOpenWindow(width, height, 8,8,8,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW);
```

and

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT);
```

And see if you get the right result or anything close, then incrementally add the details you need, like testing:

```
glfwOpenWindow(width, height, 8,8,8,8,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW);
```

then

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT);
```

and so on.

Comment: +1 Why GL_FLOAT? I tried GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and it worked; but perhaps GL_FLOAT is more efficient. I do not know, please enlighten me.

Comment: I haven't used openGL that much, but I've got used to using float. in theory bytes should be faster.